# Access - Update Imported Data

Tags: vba, ms-access

In the morning, data is pulled from **Microsoft Navision** into **Excel**...

[image]

This data is then copied into Access, where this data is utilised for production scheduling etc. When this data copied into Access, a few extra columns are added to help with scheduling and traceability, ie cut, folded, finished.

[image]

What I would like to be able to do, is that if we run the Microsoft Navision report again and lets say A3, A5 and A12 statuses have all changed to **Finished**, that when we copy and paste all these rows into Access that the status will change dependant on the Prod. Order No. related to that status.

Comment: Question is too broad. MS Access has many facilities to handle your need: datasheets, continuous forms, filtered queries, etc. Why is Excel even used?

Comment: I have edited the main body as I felt as though I may have been a little unclear in explaining

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using a temp table in Access that regularly cleans out previous and imports current Excel output. Then, run an update inner join query against your final Access table with conditional `IIF` logic.

Below are three action commands that you can save as three separate queries and run them together in VBA with `DoCmd.OpenQuery` or `CurrentDb.Execute` during your import process. Of course adjust to actual names.

**Delete** all data in  temp table

```sql
DELETE FROM ExcelTempTable;
```

**Append** to temp table

```sql
INSERT INTO ExcelTempTable
SELECT * 
FROM [Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes;Database=C:\Path\To\Workbook.xlsx].[SheetName$] AS t;
```

**Update** final table

```sql
UPDATE AccessFinalTable a
INNER JOIN ExcelTempTable e ON a.[Production Number] = e.[ProdOrderNo] 
SET a.Finished = IIF(e.Status = 'Finished', True, False),
    a.Folded = IIF(e.Status = 'Folded', True, False),
    a.Cut = IIF(e.Status = 'Cut', True, False);
```

**Append** final table *(append records of only new Production Numbers)*

```sql
INSERT INTO AccessFinalTable (Col1, Col2, Col3, ...)
SELECT e.Col1, e.Col2, e.Col3, ...
FROM ExcelTempTable e
LEFT JOIN AccessFinalTable a
ON e.[Production Number] = a.[ProdOrderNo] 
WHERE a.[Production Number] IS NULL
```

Comment: This has worked perfectly! My only other question is that upon the update being performed, how do I get any new production order numbers that were not previously within the access database to be added in upon running this update? (Sorry SQL is all new to me)

Comment: See extended answer with the `LEFT JOIN...NULL` append query that only inserts new production order numbers. Be sure to use actual column names. You can run this action any time and no duplicate product numbers will ever be appended to final table.