# Is there a way in Microsoft Access to import from an Excel File with a composite primary key?

Tags: ms-access, import, ms-access-2016, composite-primary-key

I have an excel file that comes from an export from an online platform. I want to import it into Microsoft Access. Most of the sheets contain data that are unique according to a composite key. However, when I am importing a sheet with the assistant, it is possible to let Access add a primary key, select one field as a primary key or to declare no primary key. There is no option to directly declare a composite key.

I tried to declare no primary key and to open the Create mode to declare the composite key myself. It does work, but when I rerun my saved import, the composite key is lost.

How can I import a sheet with a composite key or at least not lose my composite key when running the saved import? Is this even possible?

Comment: Table settings should not change if import to existing table. Works for me. Compound key is not lost.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. How do you import without changing table settings? I just retried to be sure, I declared a primary key in a existing table and I runned a saved import with no declared primary key. It deleted the key I declared.

Comment: I set a table with composite key. Ran an import from External Data wizard, saved its specification, then ran the saved import. Composite key is still set.

Comment: Ah, you set the table *first*! I'm ashamed, I didn't even thought about doing so. My tables were created by the import itself, that's why it overwrote the keys.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer on another topic that should suit my needs.

[Access - Update Imported Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51933282/access-update-imported-data)

The idea is to import in temporary tables, where the primary key can be an auto-increment. "Then, run an update inner join query against your final Access table".

It seems that there is no way of importing without overwriting the declared primary keys, but do tell me if you know a way of doing it, I'm still interested.

I'm not validating the answer yet as I didn't test it, but I will come back here when it will be the case.